# How to update a notification's content the proper way?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm having trouble updating a notification's content without it getting rearranged inside the notification window.

The official documentation says that as long as the `notification ID` and `TAG` are same, the notification should get replaced. And that's exactly what happening, except for one problem — It gets pushed to the top of the list every time I update it (Unless the priority is set to `LOW` or `MIN`, which I don't want).

Posting a silent notification by not setting any defaults on the builder using `setDefaults()` does the trick, but that's again not wanted.

What am I doing wrong? I know this is possible because the Gmail app is able to change its notification to an "Undo" without rearranging itself.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void showFirstNotif(){

    mNotifBuilder.setContentTitle("First")
            .setContentText("Body")
            .setWhen(activityStartTime)
            .setSmallIcon(PhotoUtils.getAppIconResId())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify("Test", NOTIF_ID, mNotifBuilder.build());

}

void showSecondNotif(){

    mNotifBuilder.setContentTitle("Second")
            .setContentText("Body")
            .setWhen(activityStartTime)
            .setSmallIcon(PhotoUtils.getAppIconResId())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify("Test", NOTIF_ID, mNotifBuilder.build());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing in your case Android is rebuilding the view all over again. You can simply call `updateNotification(String)` with a message and it will update the notification without annoying the user and rearranging your `Notification`.

I've created an example and it's working perfectly fine. Have a look :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private int mNotificationId1 = 1;
    private int mNotificationId2 = 2;
    private int mNotificationId3 = 3;
    private int mNotificationId4 = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Notification No 1");
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId1, mBuilder.build());

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Notification No 2");
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId2, mBuilder.build());

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Notification No 3");
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId3, mBuilder.build());

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Notification No 4");
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId4, mBuilder.build());

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateNotification("Notification 2 changed silently");
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateNotification(String message) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId2, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

However if you use :

```
private void updateNotification(String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(
                "Notification").setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        mNotifyManager.notify(mNotificationId2, builder.build());
    }
```

In this case although you are using the same Notification Id but it's rebuilt and hence pushed to the top as if it's a new `Notification` itself.

Comment: Nope. I have already tried this before, by only setting the properties that have to be updated. Doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Your code works because you're generating silent notifications. Setting any one from sound, vibration & LED causes it to get pushed to the top. I'm sorry if this was not clear from my post (look in the 3rd para).

Comment: @Saket The same code is working with`setDefaults()` as well. I've tested this on my device as well. I've updated the code, have a look.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by explicitly clearing the defaults flag when updating a notification. And that did the trick. Considering that your code worked at your side, I wonder if it's a newly introduced thing in Lollipop?